# Рекурсивное меню Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

по нижеследующей таблице должен собрать в один массив ID всех детей. Когда вызываю функцию index() результат должен быть: [1,2,3,4,5,6]; В чем тут моя ошибка ? Заранее спасибо за помощь.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

// Мой контроллер

```
   class MenuController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
      $id = 0;
      $menu = Menu::where('id', $id)->with('children')->first();
      $array = array();
      $a = $this->menus($menu, $array);
      dd($a);
    }

    public function menus($menu, $array)
     {
        array_push($array, $menu->id);
        if (count($menu->children->where('parent_id', $menu->id))) {
            foreach ($menu->children->where('parent_id', $menu->id) as $menu) {
                $this->menus($menu, $array);
            }
        }
        return $array;
      }
}
```

// Модель

```
class Menu extends Model
{
    public function parent(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Menu::class);
    }
    public function children(){
        return $this->hasMany(self::class,'parent_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: почему [1,2,3,4,5,6] ? разве не 2 и 3 если исккать по индексу 1?

Comment: спасибо за отзыв. Но если $id в методе index() будет равно на 3, то результат должен быть [3,4,5,6]; Извиняюсь конечно за то что не уточнил все. но после этого есть еще 1 запрос на БД $posts = Post::whereIn('menu_id', $array)->get();

Comment: Посмотрите пакет [kalnoy/nestedset](https://packagist.org/packages/kalnoy/nestedset). Он покрывает ваши потребности. Плюс использует nested sets для построения, что выгоднее обхода по дереву с использованием рекурсии.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь @Total Pusher

Answer (score 1):

Попробую сам себе ответить. Дал ожидаемый результат. Приветствуется поправка.

```
  class MenuController extends Controller
{
```

// Тут объявил глобальную переменную

$private $vaiable;

// здесь была опечатка. исправил $id на 1

```
 public function index()
    {
      $id = 1;
      $menu = Menu::where('id', $id)->with('children')->first();
      $this->vaiable= array();
      $a = $this->menus($menu);
      dd($a);
    }

public function menus($menu)
 {
    array_push($this->variable, $menu->id);
    if (count($menu->children->where('parent_id', $menu->id))) {
        foreach ($menu->children->where('parent_id', $menu->id) as $menu) {
            $this->menus($menu);
        }
    }
    return $this->variable;
  }
```

}

Comment: Не могу не поделиться что тут можно еще улучшить быстродействие. Нашел интересное сравнение [здесь](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-push.php). Конкретно в нашем примере array_push($this->variable, $menu->id) можно заменить на $this->variable[] = $menu->id; Оказывается это увеличить скорость выполнения операции.